# Is it possible for VBA to get ' character at the beginning of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a `'` character at the beginning of range in excel that determines if it's a string. This is neat because excel hides it, however supposedly it's still there. Why doesn't `.value` or `.value2` give this character. It would help so much in my program. I know I can do `''`, but that will also show in excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Range.PrefixCharacter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.prefixcharacter) to determine this.

As a small example:

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox "The prefix character is " & Sheet1.Range("A1").PrefixCharacter
End Sub
```

[image]

Or perhaps as a UDF like this:

```
Function BeginsWithQuote(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    BeginsWithQuote = rng.PrefixCharacter = "'" 
End Function
```